# Replacing Methods by Memory Address

Tags: objective-c, memory, swizzling

I was wondering if there was any way to swizzle a method by a memory address.
For example:
I have a pointer to a method 0xFFFFFF.
I have an method in my application.
I want to replace the pointer with the my method.  Is there way that I could replace this pointer in Objective-C.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a particular language in mind? COBOL? SQL? :-)

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean? Specifically, what is a "pointer to a method"? Are we talking a `struct objc_method *`? How do you come to have one with the value 0xFFFFFF? That's a rather improbable value. And what does it mean to "replace the pointer"? Just assign a new value to the variable or what?

Comment: Ok, a pointer to a method is what I find in IDA Pro.  It's a memory address associated to a function. I am talking about a '-(void)myMethod:(id)sender'.  Memory address was just an example and it's not actually that value.  And by replacing the pointer, is there any way that I could replace the memory address of the method with the memory address of my own method in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about injection.

Take a look at [mach_inject](http://guiheneuf.org/mach%20inject%20for%20intel.html)

also [Starruntime](https://github.com/StarProject/StarRuntime)

and Application Enhancer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `method_setImplementation(Method m, IMP imp)`

You have to have resolved the Method for your selector first though, using `class_getInstanceMethod` or `class_getClasssMethod`

Answer (score -2):

You could use "performSelector":

```
[object performSelector:@selector(doSomething)];
```

The selector can be stored in a variable.